# Groovy AST Transformation: Closure visibility

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to make an AST transformation which wraps method body with a closure. My problem is that this closure must access to that method parameters, but it seems that there is no visibility.

My code is available on [Github](https://github.com/sinuhepop/groovy-ast-closure-wrap). Here is what I did:

**Annotation as an entry point for AST transformation:**

```
package wrap;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformationClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompileTransformation;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(classes = { WrapTransformation.class, StaticCompileTransformation.class })
public @interface Wrap {}
```

**AST transformation (commented code with different things I tried):**

```
package wrap;

import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ASTNode;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.MethodNode;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.Parameter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.VariableScope;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ClosureExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit;
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.AbstractASTTransformation;
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformation;

@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
public class WrapTransformation extends AbstractASTTransformation {

    @Override
    public void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
        if (astNodes != null) {
            callToHandler((MethodNode) astNodes[1]);
        }
    }

    protected void callToHandler(MethodNode method) {

        method.getParameters()[0].setClosureSharedVariable(true);

        ClosureExpression body = new ClosureExpression( //

                // new Parameter[] { new Parameter(ClassHelper.OBJECT_TYPE, "stringParam") }, //
                Parameter.EMPTY_ARRAY,
                // new Parameter[0],
                // method.getParameters(),
                // null, //

                method.getCode());

        VariableScope scope = new VariableScope(method.getVariableScope());
        // method.getVariableScope().getDeclaredVariables().forEach((k, v) -> {
        // scope.putDeclaredVariable(v);
        // });
        body.setVariableScope(scope);

        MethodCallExpression callExp = new MethodCallExpression( //
                VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, //
                "handleWrapped", //
                new ArgumentListExpression(body));

        BlockStatement block = new BlockStatement();
        block.addStatement(new ExpressionStatement(callExp));
        method.setCode(block);
    }

}
```

**Base class with method where to send closure to:**

```
package wrap;

import groovy.lang.Closure;

public class BaseClass {

    public Object handleWrapped(Closure<?> closure) {
        return closure.call();
    }
}
```

**JUnit test cases:**

```
package wrap;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase;
import org.codehaus.groovy.tools.ast.TransformTestHelper;
import org.junit.Test;

import wrap.WrapTransformation;

public class WrapTransformationTest {

    @Test
    public void wrapped() throws Exception {
        run("src/test/resources/test/MyClass.groovy", "wrapped", "my string");
    }

    @Test
    public void unwrapped() throws Exception {
        run("src/test/resources/test/MyClass.groovy", "unwrapped", "my string");
    }

    protected Object run(String src, String methodName, Object... args) throws Exception {
        TransformTestHelper invoker = new TransformTestHelper(new WrapTransformation(), CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS);
        File filePath = new File(src);
        Class<?> clazz = invoker.parse(filePath);
        Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
        return clazz.getMethod(methodName, getTypes(args)).invoke(instance, (Object[]) args);
    }

    protected Class<?>[] getTypes(Object[] objs) {
        return Arrays.stream(objs).map(Object::getClass).toArray(Class[]::new);
    }
}
```

**Groovy test class:**

```
package test

class MyClass extends wrap.BaseClass {

    def unwrapped(String stringParam) {
        handleWrapped({ print stringParam })
    }

    @wrap.Wrap
    def wrapped(String stringParam) {
        print stringParam
    }
}
```

Second method should be equivalent to first one, but it isn't. First one prints correctly "my string". Second gives this exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingPropertyExceptionNoStack: No such property: stringParam for class: test.MyClass
```

After debugging with Eclipse I've found that closures which arrive at `handleWrapped` method are slightly different. First one contains an `stringParam` field, while one created with AST transformation does not.

[image]